# Select rows where a column has specific values with similar ID's

Tags: mysql

I need to write a query where I need to return rows which have similar ID's, and they need to contain specific values. In the below example, there are multiple ID's with different colors.

I need to select all rows that contain yellow, red and blue only. So here the ID of 0 and 2 would return those rows, while 1 and 3 will not be returned since it doesn't contain the specific set I need. I also need both the ID and Colors returned.

| ID | Colors |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | Yellow |
| 0 | Red |
| 0 | Blue |
| 1 | Yellow |
| 1 | Red |
| 2 | Yellow |
| 2 | Red |
| 2 | Blue |
| 3 | Red |
| 3 | Green |
| 3 | Blue |

The returned data should come back as

| ID | Colors |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | Yellow |
| 0 | Red |
| 0 | Blue |
| 2 | Yellow |
| 2 | Red |
| 2 | Blue |

I tried doing this here, but I'm assuming it's not going to work due to it selecting rows containing any of the colors. But it needs to contain all colors.

```sql
SELECT `id` , `Colors` FROM Tbl WHERE COLORS IN ('Yellow','Red','Blue') GROUP BY `id` Order BY `ID`.
```

Comment: You got only 2 rows with ID = 2 ? how do you expect 3 rows to be returned in output ?

Comment: @Akshay i just edited the question. My bad i left out that row.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

Next time please share schema with data, it saves time of others who willing to help you.

[**Demo with Given Data**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ou9ErnUrhcGFKu4nN8HvJt/0)

Please note this will just ensure all required values `IN` clause exists.

```
SELECT id, colors 
FROM Test 
WHERE id IN (
       select id from Test 
       where  colors in ('Yellow','Red', 'Blue') 
       group by id having count(1) = 3
)
```

**Sample Data:**

```
create table Test(id integer, colors varchar(10));
                                          
insert into Test(id, colors) values 
(0, 'Yellow'), (0, 'Red'), (0, 'Blue'), 
(1, 'Yellow'),(1, 'Red'),
(2, 'Yellow'),(2, 'Red'), (2,'Blue'),
(3, 'Red'), (3, 'Green'), (3, 'Blue') ;


SELECT * FROM Test WHERE id IN (select id from Test where  colors in ('Yellow','Red', 'Blue') group by id having count(1) = 3) ;
```

**Test Results:**

```
mysql> create database test;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> use test;
Database changed
mysql> create table Test(id integer, colors varchar(10));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.04 sec)

mysql> insert into Test(id, colors) values 
    -> (0, 'Yellow'), (0, 'Red'), (0, 'Blue'), 
    -> (1, 'Yellow'),(1, 'Red'),
    -> (2, 'Yellow'),(2, 'Red'), (2,'Blue'),
    -> (3, 'Red'), (3, 'Green'), (3, 'Blue') ;
Query OK, 11 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 11  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from Test;
+------+--------+
| id   | colors |
+------+--------+
|    0 | Yellow |
|    0 | Red    |
|    0 | Blue   |
|    1 | Yellow |
|    1 | Red    |
|    2 | Yellow |
|    2 | Red    |
|    2 | Blue   |
|    3 | Red    |
|    3 | Green  |
|    3 | Blue   |
+------+--------+
11 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM Test WHERE id IN (select id from Test where  colors in ('Yellow','Red', 'Blue') group by id having count(1) = 3) ;
+------+--------+
| id   | colors |
+------+--------+
|    0 | Yellow |
|    0 | Red    |
|    0 | Blue   |
|    2 | Yellow |
|    2 | Red    |
|    2 | Blue   |
+------+--------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> -- For example for Green, Red, Blue
mysql> SELECT * FROM Test WHERE id IN (select id from Test where  colors in ('Green','Red', 'Blue') group by id having count(1) = 3) ;
+------+--------+
| id   | colors |
+------+--------+
|    3 | Red    |
|    3 | Green  |
|    3 | Blue   |
+------+--------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: This makes implicit assumptions about the data set which, while probably true, should be made explicit

Comment: @strawberry you're right, I agree, thanks for the corrections